# Import JSON data into Rstudio

Tags: json, r

I've been trying to import my JSON file into R over the last couple of days, and I've tried several methods, but no luck so far.

Parts of the file look like this:

```
[{"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.46843454,"ymax":4.469002225180884,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null},
{"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.469002225180884,"ymax":4.469569910361769,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null},
{"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.469569910361769,"ymax":4.470137595542654,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null},
{"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.470137595542654,"ymax":4.470705280723538,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null}]
```

I would like to ask whether someone's able to indicate the most appropriate technique to import this .json file into R, as well as some ideas on how to clean up the data for analysis (i.e. descriptive statistics and visualisation)

Many thanks, 
Hugo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the jsonlite package:

```
    >library(jsonlite)
    >a = '[{"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.46843454,"ymax":4.469002225180884,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null},
           {"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.469002225180884,"ymax":4.469569910361769,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null},
           {"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.469569910361769,"ymax":4.470137595542654,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null},
           {"xmin":51.90606732,"xmax":51.906426887100714,"ymin":4.470137595542654,"ymax":4.470705280723538,"measures":[],"sum":0,"mean":null,"variance":-0.0,"stdev":0.0,"count":0,"maxdb":null,"mindb":null}]'
    > b = fromJSON(a)
    > b
          xmin     xmax     ymin     ymax measures sum mean variance stdev count
    1 51.90607 51.90643 4.468435 4.469002     NULL   0   NA        0     0     0
    2 51.90607 51.90643 4.469002 4.469570     NULL   0   NA        0     0     0
    3 51.90607 51.90643 4.469570 4.470138     NULL   0   NA        0     0     0
    4 51.90607 51.90643 4.470138 4.470705     NULL   0   NA        0     0     0
      maxdb mindb
    1    NA    NA
    2    NA    NA
    3    NA    NA
    4    NA    NA
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Package jsonlite clearly solves OP problem in importing this JSON structure into R.  About cleaning data, the OP has not tried anything and is not describing what is "dirty" about it.